# Android - moving views

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to move a view that acts as a background from its current location to the specified location (the location of the button that was clicked) using TranslateAnimation, However, it is starts moving the box from somewhere random. See my code below.

Layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
  >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout_test"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#E02111" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button 1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button 2" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button 3" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button 4" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button 5" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button 6" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Java Code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.*;

public class TestAnimation extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.overlapping_views);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

        //the red box
        View box = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_test);

        //Initially move the background box to button 1 
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        int[] button1Loc = new int[2]; 
        button1.getLocationOnScreen(button1Loc);
        int[] boxLocation = new int[2];
        box.getLocationInWindow(boxLocation);
        box.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(button1.getWidth() + 1,button1.getHeight() + 1));
        TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation( 0, boxLocation[0] - button1Loc[0] , 0,boxLocation[1] - button1Loc[1]);
        animation.setFillAfter(true);
        animation.setDuration(400);
        box.startAnimation(animation);  


        //add click handler on all buttons
       Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
       button.setOnClickListener(buttonClick);
       button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
       button.setOnClickListener(buttonClick);     
       button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
       button.setOnClickListener(buttonClick);
       button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
       button.setOnClickListener(buttonClick);
       button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
       button.setOnClickListener(buttonClick);
       button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
       button.setOnClickListener(buttonClick);
       button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
       button.setOnClickListener(buttonClick);

    }
    // This is the problem - it should start moving the box from its current location to the clicked button's location
    // right now it starts moving it from somewhere random :)
    private OnClickListener buttonClick = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View box = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_test);
            int[] buttonLoc = new int[2];
            v.getLocationOnScreen(buttonLoc);

            int[] boxLocation = new int[2];
            box.getLocationOnScreen(boxLocation);

             TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(
                        Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0,Animation.ABSOLUTE, buttonLoc[0] - boxLocation[0],
                        Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0,Animation.ABSOLUTE, buttonLoc[1] - boxLocation[1]
                        );
            animation.setFillAfter(true);
            animation.setDuration(400);
            box.startAnimation(animation);

        }

    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple.
You are passing some translation vector insted initial position and fianall position. Note that argument name is  xValue not xDelta like in other constructor of TranslateAnimation and you are using absolute coordinates not local.

Fix:

```
TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation( 
    Animation.ABSOLUTE, boxLocation[0], Animation.ABSOLUTE, buttonLoc[0] , 
    Animation.ABSOLUTE, boxLocation[1], Animation.ABSOLUTE, buttonLoc[1]);
```

Edit:

```
private int[] oldPos = new int[2];
private OnClickListener buttonClick = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    View box = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_test);

    int[] newPos = new int[2];
    v.getLocationInWindow(newPos);
    newPos[1] -= box.getTop();
    TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.ABSOLUTE, oldPos[0], 
            Animation.ABSOLUTE, newPos[0], 
            Animation.ABSOLUTE, oldPos[1],
            Animation.ABSOLUTE, newPos[1]);

    oldPos = newPos;

    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    animation.setDuration(400);
    box.startAnimation(animation);
}
```

There is incoherency in android. Animation.ABSOLUTE doesn't take into account status bar hight but getLocationInWindow and getLocationOnScreen does. Try to fix it by your self.

Remember that this animation doesn't move View but updates Matrix so linearLayout_test returns always the same position.

Comment: Marek R, Thanks for pointing out the xValue vs xDelta in (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html#TranslateAnimation%28int,%20float,%20int,%20float,%20int,%20float,%20int,%20float%29). The code you suggested doesn't work. Run it and see it for your self.